# Is there a more efficient way to generate 40 million alphanumeric unique random strings in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop-application

I've created a windows-forms-based small application to generate random unique alphanumeric strings with length=8. Application is working fine with small count but it got stuck for like forever when I try to generate 40 million (as per my requirement) strings. Please help me to make it efficient so that the strings could be generated quickly.

following is the complete code I've used for it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace RandomeString
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private const string Letters = "abcdefghijklmnpqrstuvwxyz";
        private readonly char[] alphanumeric = (Letters + Letters.ToLower() + "abcdefghijklmnpqrstuvwxyz0123456789").ToCharArray();
        private static Random random = new Random();

        private int _ticks;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox2.Text))
            {
                string message = "Please provide required length and numbers of strings count.";
                string title = "Input Missing";
                MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.OK;
                DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(message, title, buttons, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
            else
            {
                int ValuesCount;
                ValuesCount = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);

                for (int i = 1; i <= ValuesCount; i++)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(RandomString(Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text)));
                }
            }
        }

        public static string RandomString(int length)
        {
            const string chars = "abcdefghijklmnpqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
            return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
              .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (object row in listBox1.Items)
                {
                    sb.Append(row.ToString());
                    sb.AppendLine();
                }
                sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1); // Just to avoid copying last empty row
                Clipboard.SetData(System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.Text, sb.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _ticks++;
            this.Text = _ticks.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to add forty million *something* to a listbox ?

Comment: yeah -- don't use LINQ. do it all manually as you'd do it in C. Look in to things such as `Span<T>`. Maybe go even further and do unsafe things like `char*`

Comment: Back in the day, I tried to create a 640x480 byte array in Apple II using BASIC. Meanwhile, there was only 64K memory onboard

Comment: Are you trying to put 40 million items in a ListBox? I'm pretty sure that's the main performance problem in your code right now, especially when you don't even stop the ListBox from updating. The way you build the string is also quite inefficient - not a problem for a one-off tool, but you might want to reconsider if this is going to be used often. Finally, putting 80 MiB of data in the clipboard might be a bit too much - at that point, I'd recommend outputting directly into a file, and even better, streaming the strings as they are generated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about _code optimisations_ are off-topic. See _[Can I post questions about optimizing code on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261841/can-i-post-questions-about-optimizing-code-on-stack-overflow)_ and  _[Is it okay to ask for code optimization help?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286557/is-it-okay-to-ask-for-code-optimization-help)_ for more information.

Comment: 1 Don't use linq, 2, preallocate the memory, 3 don't put it in to a UI control, 4 use as many cores and threads as you can (will need to use something other than Random though). 5 use direct memory. this would be done in milliseconds.

Comment: @MichaelRandall - Using `[ThreadStatic] private static Random __random = new Random();` gets around the thread limitation with `Random`.

Comment: @Enigmativity ah yes, upvote, answer accepted :P

Comment: When going for unique randoms it is usually recommended to separate the two goals: create a list of unque strings and then remove from that list in random order.

Comment: @Enigmativity: actually, not quite. Field initializers for `[ThreadStatic]` don't work, because the CLR still treats the field as a single field, running type initialization only in the first thread that needs initialization, and so only gets initialized in a single thread. A common alternative that _does_ work is to reference the field in a property, and initialize it there when `null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to speed things up is to avoid LINQ. For example, take a look at these two implementations:

```
public static string LinqStuff(int length)
{
    const string chars = "abcdefghijklmnpqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
        .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
}

public static string ManualStuff(int length)
{
    const string chars = "abcdefghijklmnpqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    const int clength = 35;

    var buffer = new char[length];
    for(var i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        buffer[i] = chars[random.Next(clength)];
    }

    return new string(buffer);
}
```

Running it through this:

```
private void TestThis(long iterations)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Running {iterations} iterations...");

    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    for (long i = 0; i < iterations; ++i)
    {
        LinqStuff(20);
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"LINQ took {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms.");

    sw.Reset();
    sw.Start();
    for (long i = 0; i < iterations; ++i)
    {
        ManualStuff(20);
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"Manual took {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms.");
}
```

With this:

```
TestThis(50_000_000);
```

Yielded these results:

```
LINQ took 28272 ms.
Manual took 9449 ms.
```

So by using LINQ, you increase the time it takes to generate strings by 3 times.

You could tweak this more and squeeze out a few more seconds, probably (for example, send in the same `char[]` buffer to each call)

Comment: Why don't use [benchmark.net](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) to measure a performance?

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use linq
2. pre-allocate the memory
3. don't put it in to a UI control
4. use as many cores and threads as you can.
5. use direct memory.
6. Write the results to a file, instead of using the clipboard

This could likely be done quicker and even more efficiently, see notes. However, I can generate the chars in under 200ms

<sub>***Note** : `Span<T>` would give better results, however due to the lamdas it's just easier to take the small hit from `fixed` and use pointers*</sub>

```
private const string Chars = "abcdefghijklmnpqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

private static readonly ThreadLocal<Random> _random =
   new ThreadLocal<Random>(() => new Random());

public static unsafe void Do(byte[] array, int index)
{
   var r = _random.Value;
   fixed (byte* pArray = array)
   {
      var pLen = pArray + ((index + 1) * 1000000);
      int i = 1;
      for (var p = pArray + (index * 1000000); p < pLen; p++ ,i++)
         if ((i % 9) == 0) *p = (byte)'\r';
         else if ((i % 10) == 0) *p = (byte)'\n';
         else *p = (byte)Chars[r.Next(35)];
   }
}

public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
   var array = new byte[40000000 * ( 8 + 2)];

   var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
   Parallel.For(0, 39, (index) => Do(array, index));

   Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);

   sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
   await using (var fs = new FileStream(@"D:\asdasd.txt", FileMode.Create,FileAccess.Write,FileShare.None, 1024*1024,FileOptions.Asynchronous|FileOptions.SequentialScan))
      await fs.WriteAsync(array,0, array.Length);
   Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
}
```

**Output**

```
00:00:00.1768141
00:00:00.4369418
```

- <sub>***Note 1** : I haven't really put much thought into this apart from the raw generation, obviously there are other considerations.*</sub>
- <sub>***Note 2** : Also this will end up on the large object heap, so buyer beware. You would need to generate them straight to file so save this from ending up on the LOB*</sub>
- <sub>***Note 3** : I give no guarantees about the random distribution, likely a different random number generator would be better overall*</sub>
- <sub>***Note 4** : I used 40 index's because the math was easy, you would get slightly better results if you could match your threads to cores*</sub>

Comment: Why do `() => new Random(_seed)`? You are ensuring that every thread gets the same seed. It's far better to just call `new Random()`.

Comment: @Enigmativity oops yeah that was a left over from a test, I sort of gave up after the op went the other way, anyway, this answer will self destruct

Comment: @MichaelRandall -- this is some impressive optimization. I know we are not supposed to leave comments like "+1" or "nice job", but this is impressive.

Comment: @Andy thanks, cheers